# How can I overload the += "plus equals" operator?

Tags: operator-overloading, rust

How can I use compound operators like "+=" with custom types?

Overloading some basic operators is possible by implementing [`Add`, `Sub`, etc](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/ops/). But there does not appear to be any support for `+=`, neither is `x += y` automatically interpreted as `x = x + y` (as of the 1.0 alpha release).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is now supported, called `AddAssign` (`SubAssign`, `MulAssign`... etc).

This is a basic example:

```
use std::ops::{Add, AddAssign};
struct Float2(f64, f64);

impl AddAssign for Float2 {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: Float2) {
        self.0 += rhs.0;
        self.1 += rhs.1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't, at the moment but it's definitely something much desired. Covered by [RFC issue #393](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/393).

A very long time ago `x += y` was implemented as `x = x + y` but there was always bugs in it. I don't think any were fundamental problems with the approach at the time, but now I think the switch to the operator traits taking the arguments by-value makes that desugaring harder to work well.

Comment: This answer was correct at the time but has since been implemented. Added own answer.